# Find sum of a variable

Tags: python, sum, format

I am attempting to read a .txt file and have output print on a single line.  The .txt file has random integers written to it.  My code writes those numbers, but does not write them on the same line.  I am also attempting to find the sum of those integers and print them.  I'm not sure how close my code is, but I am stuck right now.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
def main():
    # Open a file for reading.
    infile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
    file_contents = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    total = (sum,file_contents)
    print(file_contents,'\n',end='')
    print(total)

main()
```

Here is the code that wrote the numbers.txt file if that helps

```
import random

def main():
    nums = open('numbers.txt','w') #Opens and assigns numbers.txt
    #Generates integer random integer between 4 and 7
    file_size = random.randint(4, 7) 
    #Takes the file_size integer and generates that amount
    #of random integers between 5 and 19. 
    for num in range(file_size):
       random_num = random.randrange(5,20,2)
       if random_num % 2 ==1:
           nums.write(str(random_num)+'\n')
    nums.close()
    print('Data has been written.')

main()
```

I've updated the code, still with no luck unfortunately.

```
    def main():
    # Open a file for reading.

    infile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')



    file_contents = infile.read()

    total += sum(int(file_contents.strip()))





    infile.close()

    print(file_contents)
    print(total)






main()
```

Comment: Why are you expecting everything to be on one line when your print statement is `print(file_contents,'\n',end='')`?

Comment: Are they one number per line or how is it structured?

Comment: The numbers should all appear on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sum = 0
for lineno, line in enumerate(open("numbers.txt","r")):
    try:
        sum += int(line.strip())
        sys.stdout.write(str(sum)+" ")
    except ValueError:
        print ("error in line %d"%lineno)
sys.stdout.flush()
print("sum=",sum)
```

Update example, so that it also prints the numbers

Comment: You should avoid reading the whole file with `file_object.read()`, because that loads the whole file into memory. You should use generators and iterators etc. Text file objects are iterable.

Comment: You have not completely answered the question - there are two issues, summing the integers and printing them on one line, you have summed them only

Answer (score 0):

```
total = sum(map(int,file_contents.split()))
```

**explanation**:

split() - splits the contents of the file along every whitespace (including `'\n'`

map(int, ....) - converts every element of previous result to `int`

sum() - takes in iterable, return sum. its a builtin function

Comment: Yes, this works if the file has not too many rows. Although you should not use it in a production environment. Should not keep the whole file in memory if not needed. And in this case, it is not needed.

Comment: `file_contents = infile.read()`. He has already done the mistake

Answer (score -1):

The numbers you wrote in `numbers.txt` are stored in `string` format, so when you read them from the this file, you will get them back as `string`, this means you need to convert them back to `int` but you need first to strip any white space character, because you save them with `\n` at then end.

I want to add another thing, according to Python documentation when dealing with File I/O operation:

> It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after
>   its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is
>   also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks,

So, the code can be as follows:

```
def main():
total = 0
# Open a file for reading.
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as infile:
   line = infile.readline()
   while (line):
      total += int(line.strip())
      line = infile.readline()
print(total)

main()
```

Comment: A Down vote without even a single comment??...com'n!...if I'm wrong then correct me...simply !!

Comment: I gave you an up vote, I'm still attempting to code it though.  You gave me some insight, but I still haven't quite figured it out yet.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Anthony, I've updated the code to correct, since it was giving errors, any help I can provide?